# Setting templateUrl in an AngularJS Module to increase modularity

Tags: angularjs, view, module

I have nested angularJS modules `EventList` and `EventPage`.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
app.js
EventForm
|_ EventList.js
   eventListView.html
   EventPage
   |_EventPage.js
     eventPageView.html
```

Eventlist.js:

```
angular.module('EventList', ['EventPage'])

.config([ '$routeProvider', function config($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when(Urls.EVENT_LIST, {
        templateUrl: 'app/EventList/event-list.html',
        controller: 'EventListCtrl'
      });
 }])


.controller('EventListCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', function EventListController($scope, $location, $http) {

}]);
```

EventPage.js:

```
angular.module('EventPage', [])

.config([ '$routeProvider', function config($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when(Urls.EVENT_PAGE + '/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'app/EventList/EventPage/event-page.html',
        controller: 'EventPageCtrl'
      })
 }])


.controller('EventPageCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', function EventPageController($scope, $routeParams, $http) {

  }]);
```

Obviously the `templateUrl` is hardcoded right now.  My question is what is the best way to set the `templateUrl` in the routeProvider so the modules aren't dependent on the hard coded directory structure and can be taken out and reused in other AngularJS projects without breaking?  Is there a way to just get `insertViewNameHere.html` in the current folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), this is easy. Not because modularizing AngularJS is trivial, but because all the hard work has already been done for you by the good folk doing [angular-bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/)...

When I faced this problem I simply downloaded their [Gruntfile](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) and changed every `ui.bootstrap` to `my-angular-module`. Since I mimicked their basic directory structure, it worked right out of the box.

Also, you might want to update the Angular and Bootstrap versions. E.g., change

```
ngversion: '1.0.8',
bsversion: '2.3.1',
```

to

```
ngversion: '1.2.3',
bsversion: '3.0.2',
```